# How to insert into an array? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, insert

I have a templates class that stores a collection of objects using an array and the current size. I figured out the insert and remove.  I'm having difficulty with the `isEmpty` function.  It returns `false` (as though it's not empty) even when I add say 3 and 5 and then remove 3 and 5.  It should then say `true`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

/************************************************************/
// Local includes

/************************************************************/
// Using declarations

using namespace std;

/************************************************************/
template <class T>
class Collection 
{
public:  

    Collection (int mArraySize)
    {
    m_size = mArraySize;
    array = new T[mArraySize];
    reset();
}
/************************************************************/ 

int 
size()
{
    return nextEmpty;
}

/************************************************************/ 

void
reset()
{
    nextEmpty = 0;
    nextToRead = 0;
}

/************************************************************/ 

void
insert(const T& a)
{
    if (nextEmpty < m_size)
    {
        array[nextEmpty++] = a;
    }
}

/************************************************************/ 

bool
isEmpty() 
{
   if(m_size == 0)
   {
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   }
}

/************************************************************/ 

void
makeEmpty() 
{  
    m_size = 0;
    array = NULL;
}

/************************************************************/

void
remove(const T& r) 
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == r)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (i++ < m_size)
    {
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
    }
    m_size--;
}

/************************************************************/


void
contains(T array, T target) 
{

    for(int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {

    }
}

/************************************************************/

T& 
get()
{
    return array[nextToRead++];
}

/************************************************************/

private:

T* array;
int nextEmpty;
int nextToRead;
int m_size;
};

/************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

/****************************************************************************/
// Local includes
#include "header.h"

/****************************************************************************/
// Using declarations

using namespace std;

/****************************************************************************/
// Prototypes, typedefs, etc.

bool
isEmpty();

void
makeEmpty();

void
insert();

void
remove();

void
contains();

void
testerFcn();

/****************************************************************************/

int main(int argc, char* pArgs[]) 
{
    testerFcn();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/************************************************************/

void
testerFcn()
{
    Collection <int> testArray(15);

    // insert test
    cout << "Enter numbers to add to array (enter negative number to finish): " << endl;

    for(;;)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        if (n < 0) {
            break;
        }
        testArray.insert(n);
    }

    // remove test
    cout << "Enter value to remove, (enter negative number to finish): " << endl;

    for(;;)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        if (n < 0) {
            break;
        }
        testArray.remove(n);
    }

    cout << "Is the array empty: 0 = false, 1 = true ==> " << testArray.isEmpty() << endl;

    // print what we have
    cout << "New Array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i << ":" << testArray.get() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Any reason for not using a vector?

Comment: Is this your actual code?  It's riddled with compilation errors.  Have you tried compiling it and running it to test?  I'm assuming this is homework, so I'll hold off on answering for now.  If this is homework, the most important advice I can give you is to learn to use the debugger, compile early and often, and start writing unit tests for your functionality.

Comment: Yes it is.  We`re allowed to work with other people though.  And yes, for this course, we just started using c++ so we haven`t learned vectors yet.  I know what they are but considering we haven`t technically learned them yet, I should`t use them.

Comment: I've added the homework tag for you. Please do that next time you ask a homework related question.

Comment: Yes Chad, this is my code.  I had declared my variables and everything else.  I didn`t include that here, just the functions.  I usually code in java so c++ is a completely new thing to me.  We never learned how to use the debugger and write our own tests.  Previous profs have supplied the tests.  This is the first thing I`ve ever done in c++ so I literally do not have a clue.

Comment: Can you post your entire code so that it can be compiled (including your `main()` function?  I ask because `ensureCapacity()` appears to be a member function of your "array" class, but the fact that it takes in (what appears to be a malformed) the array to be modified it could also be a standalone function.  Your `insert()` appears to be using `ensureCapacity()` as a member function.  As it is, I have to make a lot of assumptions, and I can only help you if I know my assumptions are correct.

Comment: Also, with templates your code will not compile until the template function is needed, so if you don't have some use cases to test your code is not even being compiled.  So, when you DO add your test cases and try to test things you are going to be swamped with compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking small steps here since you are new to C++. Much of your syntax is incorrect and I feel you would have done better to have some minimal class that actually compiles before you worry about fiddling about copying items and sizing arrays. But since you've got this far, here are a few general suggestions (I won't obviously write correct code for you since this is homework):

- You are using `T` interchangeably as your contained type and the type of the array. In fact calling `new T[x]` gives you a pointer-to-t, ie. a `T*`. You need to understand the distinction between the two in order to learn C or C++.
- Your `ensureCapacity` function takes two arguments. You shouldn't take the member variable `m_array` as an argument - it won't actually do at all what you're expecting here (for bonus points, think about what it *will* do). Also think about whether it makes sense for `minimumCapacity` to be a `T` as well.
- You allocate two new arrays in `ensureCapacity` and never `delete` anything. Remember that this is C++ and you must free memory somehow. Also, you should really only need one new, larger array - I think there may be a little confusion here around the difference between a `T` and a `T*` again in regard to how you can swap them.
- Are you sure about the comparison `m_array[m_size] < minimumCapacity`? What are you comparing here and why?

I hope that's of some help. Again, I suggest you try to get to grips with the basic language concepts (which are admittedly trickier than many others) before worrying too much about the logic for resizing the array - maybe starting with a very simple class with a fixed-size array and moving forward from there.

Comment: There's a lot wrong in the original question, and without any code to force the template to compile it's likely that these errors aren't being generated by the compiler yet.  Great starting point for the OP though.

Comment: Here is what I have so far.  I set up a test in my main of an integer array.  From what I can tell, my insert and remove methods work.  I`m having trouble with the isEmpty.  It returns that it isn't empty even though there are only zeros in the array spots.  Any idea on how to approach this problem?  I added my new code to the original question.

Comment: Presumably `m_size` isn't getting down to 0, probably because it starts out nonzero so if you add 5 items and remove them again it's only back to where it started? I think the root problem here is that you need to track the size of the allocated array separately to the number of things that have been put into it (via `insert()` or whatever). It looks to me like you're conflating the two.